# Typescript syntax construction `[x: string]: T` explanation

Tags: typescript, syntax

I have recently faced the following syntax in typescript project:

```
export interface EntriesToProperties<T> {
    [entryFileName: string]: T
}

export interface EntriesProperties {
    test: testEntryProperties
}

entryProperties: EntriesToProperties<EntriesProperties>;
```

and I am kinda losing the point what is happening here.

The point of confusion mostly is:

```
export interface EntriesToProperties<T> {
    [entryFileName: string]: T
}
```

I understand that `<T>` is a generic type later replaced with `<EntriesProperties>`, but how than it is applied to `[entryFileName: string]: T` and what is `[entryFileName: string]: T` here at all?

Is it a destructuring syntax? If yes, why there is a type annotated variable name `entryFileName: string`? And how to use it later if there is no assignment following with declaration?

Is it an array literal? So will that be an array of strings, array of `EntriesProperties` elements or will it be an array `testEntryProperties` elements after `<T>` is replaced with `<EntriesProperties>`? If it won't be an array of strings - what `: string` type annotation does in it?

Comment: It's simply put the indexing key for the object entry, its name can be anything, usually it's just `key` or `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mike S. lead I was able to find articles with more detailed answer.

This construction `[entryFileName: string]: T` is a special 'index signature' syntax for an object . It is used to define a type of objects it can store, so it means that

```
interface EntriesToProperties<T> {
    [entryFileName: string]: T
}
```

is an object that can store only objects of type `<T>` that are indexed and aso can be accessed by `entryFileName: string`. Effectively it creates type-safe map-like object, that has some additional features comparing to built-in Map and Record.

More info:

https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-type-safe-dictionaries-in-typescript-a072d750cbdf

Comment: In the TypeScript Handbook, in the chapter about interfaces, also see [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).